# How to pass cmake argument to setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I'm [trying to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60386499/exception-not-found-python-cv2-pypy36-pp73-x86-64-linux-gnu-so-co) opencv-python for pypy by `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. I need to pass `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/snap/pypy3/50/bin/libpypy3-c.so` to cmake during module install or compile will fail. How to pass it to `setup.py`?

Comment: It seems like you already ask about this in your *other* question. Why are you creating a separate question about the same topic? Is this somehow different?

Comment: The other one is asking for a full working example of how to fix the error and compile opencv for pypy. This is asking how to pass this path via setup, which may or may not be the answer to the other question.